# How to guarantee contents dimensions of WPF window are always the same regardless of window trim thickness?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, layout

Using this image to clearly show the problem:

[Red box background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gTH2.png)

If I do this in Visual Studio...

[Designer layout A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znve3.png)

... the image gets clipped because the trim of the window is fatter at runtime than the pseudo-trim in VS designer:

[Runtime dimensional change A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f1ZJ.png)

If I increase the window size in Visual Studio to look like this...

[Designer layout B (with window size increased to match Windows 7 trim thickness)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQiE1.png)

... the result looks correct:

[Runtime dimensions look correct... for Windows 7 trim thickness only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Jbv.png)

*I've tried the same steps with and without a window Grid. The result is the same.*

————

As a point of reference, macOS/Cocoa windows are defined by the size of their content area to avoid this problem.

In other words, if I set a window in Xcode to be 300 x 300, at runtime its **content** view frame will always be 300 x 300 regardless of how Apple changes the window trim dimensions from version to version of the OS.

————

**What is the WPF method of achieving window-trim-agnostic content dimensions?**

Comment: "I've tried this without and without a window Grid" - tried what??

Comment: @ASh The steps outlined in the question.

Comment: @ASh I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I can list a dozen of ways to create layout which will look the same - including the one of "load someone's else screenshot in an Image" - but usually questions contain a [mcve], and don't force me to resort to that. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Jbv.png) there is some markup in background, but you minght want to delete it completely (for secrecy and security reasons)

Comment: @ASh A minimal reproducible example implies code. This is a codeless example. Everything I'm doing is in the designer. I'm not sure what "load someone's else screenshot in an Image" is referring to. And the markup in the background of the two runtime screenshots means absolutely nothing in a demo project I created specifically to demonstrate this problem specifically for posting this question.

Comment: [Window.SizeToContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @ASh Sorry I missed the "without and without" typo in the question and your comment. It's been corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks. That worked great. I figured it had to be something simple that I was missing. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Use GetSystemMetrics to tell you the width and hight of the border to the window (via SM_CXSIZEFRAME & SM_CYSIZEFRAME) and add it to the size of window you are opening or resizing.